# Do the premium VFS Services include the application fee?

Tags: visas, uk, vfs-global

I started my application on the vfs site to apply in New York. When it came to submitting Payment I see it brought me to the regular application centers with the option of regular service or priority. However there were no immediate appointments.

I then went to the premium service website and purchased the Silver package referencing the application mentioned above. My question is; is the premium silver package an extra fee on top of the regular application fee? Do I still go and pay the visa fee on the application?

The process is a bit confusing and there appears to be no number to call. Please help.

Answer (score 3):

The application fee is included within the silver package valued at $875, the only thing that would be extra is the 'walk in without appointment' service which is only available as an add on for an additional $75.

For any further questions they offer an [email contact](https://contact-ukvi.homeoffice.gov.uk/app/international/payment/language/English) service and have a specific number for English speaking calls coming from outside the UK: 00 44 203 481 1736